Modify format in table1
One of the vignette examples of table1, shows a reformatting of the continuous summary stats:
my.render.cont <- function(x) {
    with(stats.apply.rounding(stats.default(x), digits = 2),
         c("", "Mean (SD)" = sprintf("%s (&plusmn; %s)",  MEAN, SD)))
}

How do I also apply a comma thousand separator in addition to the above?

Using ?table1::stats.apply.rounding we can discover that the default rounding function is:

rounding.fn The function to use to do the rounding. Defaults to signif_pad.

as well as:

... Further arguments.

While not clearly stated often the purpose of ellipses is to pass additional arguments to other functions.
If we then check ?table1::signif_pad:

... Further options, passed to formatC (which is used internally). Not all options will work, but some might be useful (e.g. big.mark, decimal.mark).

And a short test later, we find that it is possible to pass big.mark = "," to table1::stats.apply.rounding() through to formatC() like so:
library(table1)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(x = sample(1000:9999, 10))

my.render.cont <- function(x) {
  with(
    x |>
      stats.default() |>
      stats.apply.rounding(digits = 2, big.mark = ","),
    c(
      "",
      "Mean (SD)" = sprintf("%s (&plusmn; %s)", MEAN, SD)
    )
  )
}

table1(~ x, data = data, render.continuous = my.render.cont)


Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1
